# Cannot resize Macintosh HD using (supposedly) available free space

Tags: macos, disk-utility, partition

I partitioned my hard drive in order to install Ubuntu, but I now would like to reclaim that space and add it back to my Macintosh HD. I managed to delete the Linux Filesystem and Swap, and Disk Utility shows that I have some free space:

[image: disk utility screenshot]

However, I cannot resize my Macintosh HD (which is the 200 GB slice) using the simple method of clicking and dragging in Disk Utility. The output of some common disk usage tools is below:

[image: screenshot of disk usage terminal output]

I have tried repairing all disks and the problem persists. I am running OS X El Capitan Version 10.11.5. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

**This worked for me:**

On the left is a list of drives your Macbook or iMac can see.  Select the drive from this left menu that has the partitions you want to combine.

In the top of the window will be five tabs/buttons.  Choose the middle one called “partition”.

Select the partition from the big block on the left that you want to remove.  With the partition selected hit the small “-” at the bottom left corner to delete the partition.  This small “-” is near the “+”.  This will bring up a message, okay that and it will delete the extra partition and leave empty space.

Now we need to fill that empty space with your main partition.  Still on this partition screen, you will see your main partition block has three small lines in the bottom corner.  Like the corner of a piece of paper when you are turning a page.  Click on here and you can drag the box size.

Drag the box size until it fills the space completely.  Hit apply and it will then make a big block, single partition

Comment: Unfortunately that method is not available to me since for some reason the "+" and "-" buttons on the disk-utility partition page are grayed out and cannot be pressed. I have thoroughly explored the options available to me through the disk-uility GUI and believe that the solution will need to involve the command line.